# How can I get a count of all the texts I received from a given phone number in Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice

I want to get a count of all the text messages I've received from a specific phone number in Google Voice.

I know I can open the conversation history for a given phone number and manually count the texts but that is not practical given the large volume of texts.

I don't have archives of the notification emails sent by Google Voice, so I can't use my email client to get the count.

Is there another option within the Google Voice web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in Google Voice to my knowledge, but here is a "quick and dirty" solution using either MS Excel or Google Sheets.

Because each of the contact's incoming messages includes a specific text string, it can be leveraged using a spreadsheet formula to count all instances of that text string within the conversation, which is equivalent to the incoming message count.

1. Copy the Google Voice conversation and paste it into Column A of your spreadsheet.
2. From your pasted data, identify the text string **`[text]`** to be counted. It will match the pattern **`"Message by [contact]"`**. For example, if the contact is "Google Support", then it will match **`"Message by Google Support"`**.
3. Place the following formula in B1 after replacing **`[text]`** with the value identified in the previous step:

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH([text], A:A),))
                                 ↓ 
                                 ↓
   =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH("Message by Google Support",A:A),))
   ```